# Can an flash menu coded in AS3 be used in Flex Builder 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I wish to use a flash menu coded in AS3 in a flex project. The menu in question is at:

http://www.oxylusflash.com/flashfiles/horizontal-resizable-ultra-menu-as3

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. **But I don't think you should** (for a number of reasons that are probably a little out of the scope of this question).

You'd subclass UIComponent, add just the menu and override accessors for width and height and make sure, the flex app can interface with the menu and vice versa. I have no access to the code, but this should also be quite trivial.

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Depends how it's built, but it should be relatively easy to create a Flex version from scratch.

Comment: I do not want to create a version from scratch since I would not be able to get the same finish since I am not a flash coder. Plus it would definitely take more time. The product above costs only $8.